# Tensorflow1.2 caused the error: can't pickle _thread.lock objects on deepcopy or Cpickle

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, deep-copy, autoencoder

For

```
encoder_cell = copy.deepcopy(cell)
```

or

```
encoder_cell = cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(cell, -1))
```

In tensoflow1.2, it raise error like:

```
    encoder_cell = cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(cell, -1))
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

but it works well on tensorflow1.0.1

Comment: In general, TensorFlow Python API objects (and related objects like `tf.Tensor`, `tf.Operation`, or the RNN cell layers) aren't `pickle`-able. Do you need to make a `copy.deepcopy()` of the `cell` object, or could a different approach work?

Comment: more specific suggestion? I am porting someone else code.

Comment: Well, does it work if you replace the line `encoder_cell = copy.deepcopy(cell)` with a simple shallow copy: `encoder_cell = cell`? If not, can you share more details of the code? (Because we don't know how `cell` was created or if it's meaningfully stateful....)

Comment: @mrry , it does can 'pass' with copy.copy(shallow copy) but will caused another error.  The code which i am working on is derivative of seq2seq, and it looks this is old issue in tensorflow, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11157

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with legacy `seq2seq.py`, then add this to your script:

```py
setattr(tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell, '__deepcopy__', lambda self, _: self)
setattr(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell, '__deepcopy__', lambda self, _: self)
setattr(tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell, '__deepcopy__', lambda self, _: self)
```